# Artifact's permissions issue with terrafrom

Tags: terraform

I am trying to create a service account using terraform and I also want to apply multiple permissions to that account using terraform.

```
# create artifact register
resource "google_artifact_registry_repository" "yacht-away" {
  provider = google-beta

  location      = "asia-south1"
  repository_id = "yacht-away"
  description   = "yacht-away docker repository with iam"
  format        = "DOCKER"
}

# create service account
resource "google_service_account" "yacht-away-service-acc" {
  provider = google-beta
  account_id   = "yacht-away-service-ac"
  display_name = "Yacht Away Service Account"
}
```

However, I constantly see this error. I have verified the value of `location` everywhere it is the same as mentioned above. So probably that is not the issue. The service account being used by the terraform has project editor access and I have also tried after providing it owner access.

```
Error: Error when reading or editing Resource "artifactregistry repository \"projects/dhb-222614/locations/asia-south1/repositories/yacht-away\"" with IAM Member: Role "roles/artifactregistry.reader" Member "serviceAccount:yacht-away-service-ac@dhb-222614.iam.gserviceaccount.com": Error retrieving IAM policy for artifactregistry repository "projects/dhb-222614/locations/asia-south1/repositories/yacht-away": googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission
```

So I don't understand where am I going wrong.

Comment: Can you show how you're assigning the role? In the snippet you only show the creation of the repo and the SA but not the permission configuration